# How to Clear an observable collection without using clear method

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When i am trying to clear my observable collection it is crashing.Is there any 
other way to clear it??

```
ObservableCollection<Group> _groupList = new ObservableCollection<Group>();
public ObservableCollection<Group> GroupList
{
    get
    {
        return _groupList;
    }

    set
    {
        _groupList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("GroupList"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code where you clear the collection

Answer (score 1):

You can simple make a new collection:

```
GroupList = new ObservableCollection<Group>();
```

Comment: Note that this will break your databinding and you have to set your `BindingContext` again

Answer (score 0):

There's a clear function

```
GroupList.Clear();
```

or

```
 GroupList = new ObservableCollection<Group>();
```

Also try declare you list this way :

```
ObservableCollection<Group> _groupList;
public ObservableCollection<Group> GroupList
{
    get { return _groupList; }
    set { SetValue(ref _groupList, value); }
}
```

Comment: Quote from question: > When i am trying to clear my observable collection it is crashing.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis updated answer. we need more information than just "crashing"

Comment: He posted it under an answer I deleted earlier. I already asked for more code on how and when he is clearing the collection. But no anwer